# cs231n Convoluted Neural networls

Tags: computer-vision, conv-neural-network, calculus

I was watching the online lecture of CS 231n from Stanford. I have a question, maybe I'm getting confused for some reason. The link is:
[the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QWfmCyLEQ8U)

Go to 35:46 and in the backward function, the formula for dx is:

```
dx = self.y * dz.
```

That I don't get since

```
z = x*y.
```

So

```
dx = dz/y
```

Can someone please explain me why the difference is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a weird notation in his code (**dz,dx,dy** are not used in their usual sense). the variable **dz** here denotes the derivative of the cost function **L** (of the complete neural network) with respect to **z**, while the derivatives of **L** with respect to **x** and **y** are noted **dx** and **dy**.The derivative of **z** with respect to **x**, which is **y**, is simply given by **self.y**. With these notations in mind, the rest follows from the chain rule.

Comment: So, correct me if I'm wrong. dx is nothing the product of influence of z on L (dL/dz) and local gradient (influence) of y on x (which is nothing but y). Is this correct?

Comment: dx is the product of the influence of z on L  with the influence of x on z. The neuron computes z=x*y,  so both x and y influence z, but at no time does y have an influence on x. I hope that helps!

Comment: Now it makes perfect sense. Your explanation and just going back to it made perfect sense. Thanks.